# UITabBarController image is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using UITabBarController which has four view controllers. these are Dashboard, ComposeMessage, PostMessage and Profile. I want to use images in tabBarItem. but the problem is images are not showing in UITabBar.

```
    UITabBarController *customBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    DashboardViewController *social = [[DashboardViewController alloc]init];
    social.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prifile_tab.png"];
    [customBar addChildViewController:social];

    ComposeMessageViewController *composeMessage = [[ComposeMessageViewController alloc]init];
    composeMessage.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer_post_tab.png"];
    [customBar addChildViewController:composeMessage];


    PostMessageViewController *postMessage = [[PostMessageViewController alloc] init];
    postMessage.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer_post_tab.png"];
    [customBar addChildViewController:postMessage];

    ProfileViewController *profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    profile.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer_post_tab.png"];
    [customBar addChildViewController:profile];

    NSArray *tabBarArray = @[social,composeMessage,postMessage,profile];
    [customBar setViewControllers:tabBarArray];

    self.window.rootViewController = customBar;
```

Comment: Are your images alpha masks? If not than you should set the image's rendering mode to always original like:
`UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageName:@"timer_post_tab.png"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Tabbar sizes should be like this

@1x size 25 x 25 (maximum: 48 x 32)

@2x size 50 x 50 (maximum: 96 x 64)

@3x : size 75 x 75 (maximum: 144 x 96)

Answer (score 1):

Just check ur image sizes are proper or not ..u should give only valid size images nor random sizes